# Read floppy from OpenVMS machine

Tags: linux, floppy, openvms

I have a floppy I need to read the contents from - unfortunately it was formatted and the data written on an OpenVMS server. I believe the floppy is formatted "Files-11" or similarly ODS2 and I can see parts of the MDT and file contents through a hex editor, however I would love to be able to mount this and actually read the files off in a sane, normal way.

Is there an ODS2/Files-11 FUSE module or other kernel module I can install to read this format? Any standalone utilities that can understand a floppy image taken with dd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at  [**VMS2linux**](http://www.vms2linux.de/) it provides tools that may help.

Comment: Use dd to read off the entire image then loop mount the file created so that you don't have to mess with the floppy all the time. Aren't you afraid that it will crumble to dust as it joins its brethren in oblivion?

Comment: I actually found an "ods2.zip" that contains source and binaries for a bunch of operating systems. Thanks for getting for off in the right direction. http://www.process.com/openvms/